# Direction of walking BingMaps Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I have my Lumia without compass. I am a 'traveller' so I created small app on my phone to pin my points on bing maps.

There is my navigation method:

```
                        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };

                        timer.Tick += async (x, y) =>
                        {
                            Geolocator myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
                            Geoposition myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
                            Geocoordinate myGeocoordinate = myGeoposition.Coordinate;
                            GeoCoordinate myGeoCoordinate = CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeocoordinate(myGeocoordinate);
                            double distance = Math.Round(DistanceTo(myGeocoordinate.Latitude, myGeocoordinate.Longitude, toNavigate.cords.Latitude, toNavigate.cords.Longitude), 2);
                            distanceTextBox.Text = distance.ToString() + " kilometers to " + toNavigate.tag;
                        };
```

In the method I see ónline' my road`s length.

Having my current GeoCoordinate and GeoCoordinate of target point I would like to add this method  arrow image which shows me my direction I am going.
Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is calculate the heading from one coordinate to another. You can find some code on how to do this in C# here: http://mapstoolbox.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Maps.Spatialtoolbox/Source/Microsoft.Maps.SpatialToolbox.Core/SpatialTools.cs

Look for the CalculateHeading method. You will need to update the code to use a GeoCoordinate object, unless you decide to use this full library of spatial tools, which support WP8.